# How to get stored procedure return value?

Tags: c++, sql, sql-server, ado

I am using MS SQL and C++ Ado lib.

My stored procedure is not returning a return value.

Stored procedure :

```
Alter Procedure [test]   
select value from test_tbl;    
Return 1
```

(1 means Success)

C++ source code:

```
_ParameterPtr  paramRet = m_pCommand->Parameters->Append(m_pCommand->CreateParameter("RETURN_VALUE", adInteger, adParamReturnValue, 4));        
_variant_t testval = m_pCommand->Parameters->GetItem("RETURN_VALUE")->Value;
```

`testval` is empty.

How can I get the return value?

Comment: had you tried executing the procedure in SSMS and confirmed it does return a value?

Comment: What do you expect that return value represent? You should reserve return values to indicate basic information about the state of the result. If the stored procedure is designed to return data to a caller, you may consider using output parameters.

Comment: Have you tried to use Google? e.g. searching for "c++ execute stored procedure on SQL Server" returns a number of results.

Comment: Dr. Stitch//yes, ssms comfirmed.... ex) first low index (0) value (0), second low "low name nothing (1)